# Why does the ternary operator unexpectedly cast integers?

Tags: java, casting, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

I have seen it discussed somewhere that the following code results in `obj` being a `Double`, but that it prints `200.0` from the left hand side.

```
Object obj = true ? new Integer(200) : new Double(0.0);

System.out.println(obj);
```

Result: 200.0

---

However, if you put a different object in the right hand side, e.g. `BigDecimal`, the type of `obj` is `Integer` as it should be.

```
Object obj = true ? new Integer(200) : new BigDecimal(0.0);

System.out.println(obj);
```

Result: 200

---

I presume that the reason for this is something to do with casting the left hand side to a `double` in the same way that it happens for `integer`/`double` comparisons and calculations, but here the left and right sides do not interact in this way.

Why does this happen?

Comment: I'm not versed in Java, but the right question to ask is "what is the type of a ternary conditional expression?"

Comment: Have to admit this is pretty messed up stuff. Really surprised me when I ran this in NetBeans and `obj.getClass()` shows `Double`. What the hell, man.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to read [section 15.25 of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.25).

In particular:

> Otherwise, if the second and third operands have types that are convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric types, then there are several cases:
>
> - If one of the operands is of type byte or Byte and the other is of type short or Short, then the type of the conditional expression is short.
> - If one of the operands is of type T where T is byte, short, or char, and the other operand is a constant expression of type int whose value is representable in type T, then > - the type of the conditional expression is T.
> - If one of the operands is of type Byte and the other operand is a constant expression of type int whose value is representable in type byte, then the type of the conditional expression is byte.
> - If one of the operands is of type Short and the other operand is a constant expression of type int whose value is representable in type short, then the type of the conditional expression is short.
> - If one of the operands is of type; Character and the other operand is a constant expression of type int whose value is representable in type char, then the type of the conditional expression is char.
> - Otherwise, binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is applied to the operand types, and the type of the conditional expression is the promoted type of the second and third operands. Note that binary numeric promotion performs unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) and value set conversion (§5.1.13).

So [binary numeric promotion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#170983) is applied, which starts with:

> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order, using widening conversion (§5.1.2) to convert operands as necessary:
>
> - If any of the operands is of a reference type, unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) is performed. Then:
> - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.

That's exactly what happens here - the parameter types are converted to `int` and `double` respectively, the second operand (the third in the original expression) is then of type `double`, so the overall result type is `double`.

Comment: Gah Jon Skeet beat me to it :) +1

Comment: @VivinPaliath Yeah me too, but that's alright because I was just about to steal the citation of his from another question about the ternary operator we had some time ago ;-)

Comment: While I'm glad there's documentation on it, I can't see the reason for it anywhere in there (but I'm sure I'm not looking properly). It seems to me that this is an assignment and there is no need for the binary numeric promotion, am I missing something?

Comment: Same here... I'm a bit bewildered why this would be deemed necessary. It maybe useful from a purely functional point of view, but with the use of reflection and `Class` checks abound this seems like a huge gotcha in some cases.

Comment: @HXCaine: What would you want this to do in the case of the same types but *primitive* ones? Bear in mind that the type of the expression is separate from the assignment part.

Comment: Oh, I see. So syntactically, the conditional expression needs to have a collective type for parsing/compiling purposes even before the condition is evaluated?

Comment: @HXCaine: Yes. The compiler decides what the type is, then considers whether it's convertible to the target of the assignment. Note that generic type inference is one counterexample to that, but it's the only one I can think of offhand :)

Answer (score 3):

### Numeric conversion in the conditional operator ? :

In the conditional operator *`a`*`?`*`b`*`:`*`c`*, if both *`b`* and *`c`* are *different numeric* types, the following conversion rules are applied at *compile* time to make their types *equal*, in order:

- The types are converted to their corresponding *primitive* ones, which is called *unboxing*.
- If one operand were a *constant* `int` (not `Integer` before unboxing) whose value is representable in the other type, the `int` operand is converted into the other type.
- Otherwise the smaller type is converted into the next greater one until both operands have the same type. The conversion orders are:
  `byte` -> `short` -> `int` -> `long` -> `float` -> `double`
  `char` -> `int` -> `long` -> `float` -> `double`

Eventually the whole conditional expression gets the type of its second and third operands.

Examples:
If you combine `char` with `short`, the expression becomes `int`.
If you combine `Integer` with `Integer`, the expression becomes `Integer`.
If you combine `final int i = 5` with a `Character`, the expression becomes `char`.
If you combine `short` with `float`, the expression becomes `float`.

In the question's example, 200 is converted from `Integer` into `double`, 0.0 is unboxed from `Double` into `double` and the whole conditional expression becomes `double` which is eventually boxed into `Double` because `obj` is of type `Object`.

Comment: The aim of this answer is to express the complete definition including unboxing, numerical promotion etc. with a few simple rules which are easy to remember.

Answer (score 0):

**Example:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 10;
    int i2 = 10;
    long l = 100;
    byte b = 10;
    char c = 'A';
    Long result;
    // combine int with int result is int compiler error
   // result = true ? i : i2; // combine int with int, the expression becomes int
    //result = true ? b : c; // combine byte with char, the expression becomes int

    //combine int with long result will be long
    result = true ? l : i; // success - > combine long with int, the expression becomes long
    result = true ? i : l; // success - > combine int with long, the expression becomes long
    result = true ? b : l; // success - >  combine byte with long, the expression becomes long
    result = true ? c : l; // success - >  char long with long, the expression becomes long

    Integer intResult;
    intResult = true ? b : c; // combine char with byte, the expression becomes int.
   // intResult = true ? l : c; // fail combine long with char, the expression becomes long.

}
```