# what are unary code means in java

Tags: java

I'm came with two different types with same code which give same result.

First one is

```
public String gender(int num){
    if (num==0){
        return "Female";
    } else{               
        return "Male";
    }
}
```

Second one is

```
public String gender(int num){
    return num == 0 ? "Female" : "Male" ;
}
```

Can you tell me what is the different with these two cord patterns? (Not of course code length.) One of my friend told me second code patten is called Unary code in java or  something like that. I feel this way is very efficient. So I want to learn about that. Please help me.

Comment: actualy there is no difference. only thing is second option is a short  form of first one and it is represented by ternary operator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its called [ternary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) operator

```
return  num == 0 ? "Female" : "Male";
```

means same as

```
if (num==0){ 
  return "Female"; 
}else{
  return "Male"; 
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for my mistake and :( great to have you guys.. :)

Comment: more ever if you will use ternary operator it will do automatic upcasting

Comment: can you explane me about this upcasting plz

Comment: @user2867987 I have added an answer , Please have a look

Answer (score 2):

It's [`ternary operator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) and equlas to `if-else`

```
 result = someCondition ? value1 : value2;
```

**So based up on the condition, the result variable gets a value.**

That's short hand form of `if else`.

> Another conditional operator is ?:, which can be thought of as shorthand for an if-then-else statement. This operator is also known as the ternary operator because it uses three operands. In the following example, this operator should be read as: "If someCondition is true, assign the value of value1 to result. Otherwise, assign the value of value2 to result."

Comment: @suresh is these ternary operators only used for if else conditions, or can we use them for any others.

Comment: @user2867987 If you see the quoted text in my answer, it replace of only if-else  `which can be thought of as shorthand for an if-then-else statement.`. So in other places you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
 return num == 0 ? "Female" : "Male" ;
        _________     ^            ^
            ^         |            |
            |        Return this   |__ Return this if expression false
        Expression  if expression 
                       true
```

It returns the result of the expression - (num == 0 ? "Female" : "Male")

It checks if num is equal to 0 or not. If yes the result is the first argument ie "Female" else the second argument ie "Male" if num is non zero.

Comment: yeah I got it :) @Ankit are these ternary operators only using for if else. or are there any conditions.

Answer (score 0):

[Have a look at this Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002603/why-does-the-ternary-operator-unexpectedly-cast-integers)  in which it is casting the Integer to Double ,

There is no performance advantage in using the conditional operator versus using an if statement

Using ternary provides more better readability to the code. You are trading one line which concisely expresses what you want against nine lines of effectively clutter.

Comment: I got that. :)but minimizing the no of line isn't that some good ?