# Conditional if-else statement in java

Tags: java, if-statement, int, double

I am unable to understand how the below code print 50.0

```
public class Pre
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int x=10;
        System.out.println((x > 10) ? 50.0 : 50); //output 50.0
    }
}
```

It should print 50 (I guess) not 50.0

Isn't the above code is equivalent to below code?,

```
public class Pre
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int x=10;
        if(x>10)
            System.out.println(50.0);
        else
            System.out.println(50);//output
    }
}
```

If they are equivalent,then why the difference in output ?

Comment: Because they are not equivalent. There's a dupe somewhere.

Comment: @Sotirious-But in most of the books,it is mentioned that the 1st code can be thought of an equivalent to 2nd one

Comment: @RajMalhotra yes they can be thought of as equivalent; but they are not identical... it is a simplification that is used to teach beginners but it is not the whole truth.

Comment: I don't think that this question is a duplicate of [Why does the ternary operator unexpectedly cast integers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002603/why-does-the-ternary-operator-unexpectedly-cast-integers), although they are very similar. This question is about primitives; that one is about boxed numbers (which is much weirder)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java ensure your types are coherent, so in the first statement

```
(x > 10) ? 50.0 : 50
```

You have a double first, so the return type of the expression is double, and the litteral int is converted to double. Hence the two sides of the conditional are the same!

If you change it to

```
System.out.println((x > 10) ? 50.0 : 49);
```

It prints 49.0.

the if/else is not an expression, hence it doesn't have to do any conversion.

Answer (score 6):

It's printing 50.0 because in the first case you are calling the `OutputStream.println(double)` method, because your first expression returns a `double` irrespective of your condition.

But in the second case you are calling `OutputStream.println(int)` method.

Answer (score 5):

The type of the ternary conditional operator - `(x > 10) ? 50.0 : 50)` is determined by both the 2nd and 3rd operands. In your case, it must be able to contain the values of both `50.0` and `50`, so its type is `double`.

Therefore, even when the expression returns `50`, it is cast to double, and you see `50.0`.

If you change

```
System.out.println((x > 10) ? 50.0 : 50);
```

to

```
System.out.println((x > 10) ? 50.0 : 10);
```

You'll see `10.0` printed, which will make it obvious that the correct value (the right side of the `:`) is returned.