# Java - ternary operator weird behaviour

Tags: java, double, ternary-operator

I was trying to remove the `fractional` part from a `double` in case it is whole using:

```
(d % 1) == 0 ? d.intValue() : d
```

And encountered the following behavior which i don't understand:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double d = 5D;
    System.out.println((d % 1) == 0);                               // true
    System.out.println((d % 1) == 0 ? d.intValue() : "not whole");  // 5
    System.out.println((d % 1) == 0 ? d.intValue() : d);            // 5.0
}
```

As you can see on the third line, the operator chooses the `else` value - `5.0` even though the condition `(d % 1) == 0` is met.

What's going on here?

Comment: It chooses `d.intValue()` in both cases, it just performs conversions to make sure the second and third argument have the same type.

Comment: Could probably considered as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002603/why-does-the-ternary-operator-unexpectedly-cast-integers (and all its duplicates) ...

Comment: @Marco13, i was not aware that casting was the problem while posting the question. maybe it's a duplicate by hindsight..

Comment: You are trying to remove the *fractional part* from a `double`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The return type of the ternary conditional operator must be such that both the 2nd and 3rd operands can be assigned to it.

Therefore, in your second case, the return type of the operator is `Object` (since both `d.intValue()` and `"not whole"` must be assignable to it) while in the third case it is `Double` (since both `d.intValue()` and `d` must be assignable to it).

Printing an `Object` whose runtime type is `Integer` gives you `5` while printing a `Double` gives you `5.0`.

Comment: But why is it being cast to `Object` and not `String` when both can be assigned to a `String`?

Comment: @Daniel Actually, `Integer` cannot be assigned to a `String`, it has to be converted to a String (for example, by using `Integer`'s `toString`) first. It's only converted to a String in your example in order to be printed by println.

Answer (score 11):

The type of an expression `a ? b : c` is always the same as `c` or the closest common parent of `b` and `c`.

```
System.out.println((d % 1) == 0 ? d.intValue() : "not whole");  // Comparable a parent of Integer and String
System.out.println((d % 1) == 0 ? d.intValue() : d);            // Double is a widened int
```

BTW `d % 1` will only check it is a whole not, not that it's small enough to fit in an`int` value.  A safer check is to see if the value is the same when cast to an `int` or `long`

```
double d = 5.0;
if ((long) d == d)
    System.out.println((long) d);
else
    System.out.println(d);
```

or you can prevent it widening the `long` back to a double with

```
double d = 5.0;
System.out.println((long) d == d ? Long.toString((long) d) : Double.toString(d));
```

Comment: Thanks, in my case (number represents csat) the max possible value is 5 so life's thankfully simpler than that..

Answer (score 3):

It chooses correctly. Then it wraps it in double. These are 3 key points:

1. If the second and third operands have the same type, that is the type of the conditional expression. In other words, you can avoid the whole mess by steering clear of mixed-type computation.
2. If one of the operands is of type T where T is byte , short , or char and the other operand is a constant expression of type int whose value is representable in type T, the type of the conditional expression is T.
3. Otherwise, binary numeric promotion is applied to the operand types, and the type of the conditional expression is the promoted type of the second and third operands.

Answer (score 1):

In your case the second and third arguments of the ternery operator are types "int" and "Double". Java must convert these values to the same type so they can be returned from the ternary operator. The rules for doing this are given in the Java language specification. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25

In your case these rules result in the conversion of both parameters to type "double" (the "Double" is unboxed, the int is value-converted).

The fix is to cast the arguments to the ternary operator so that they are of the same type (there may be more brackets in the below than strictly needed, i'm a bit rusty on java operator precedence rules).

```
System.out.println((d % 1) == 0 ? ((Number)(d.intValue())) : (Number)d);
```