# Different result with ternary operator and if else

Tags: java

```html
1. hasTimePeriodExtraDays = (externalSystemConfigsDTO == null) ? true : externalSystemConfigsDTO.hasTimePeriodExtraDays();

2. if(externalSystemConfigsDTO == null){
            hasTimePeriodExtraDays = true;
        } else {
            hasTimePeriodExtraDays = externalSystemConfigsDTO.hasTimePeriodExtraDays();
        }
```

the 1 clause not passing UT as nullpointer thrown, but the 2nd pass the UT.

Comment: What do you mean by "UT"?

Comment: I suspect UT means "unit test." Is that correct?

Comment: What unit tester are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does hasTimePeriodExtraDays() return? A boolean primitive, or a Boolean object? And the same for hasTimePeriodExtraDays?

The ternary brings an unseen autoboxing to ensure that both sides are of the same type, which might explain it.

E.G. if it returns a Boolean and the variable is a Boolean, in your IF, it works fine even if the return value is null.

But in your teenary it could be casting both to a boolean primitive - if the return is null you’d get a NullPointerException as you are seeing.

Further info - [Why does the ternary operator unexpectedly cast integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002603/why-does-the-ternary-operator-unexpectedly-cast-integers)

Comment: Yup, this seems to be the explanation